# How to get date in the name of excel file which is created using python?

Tags: excel, string, python-3.x, datetime

I want to save df values into excel file which should be using following convention - "ComparisonReport-(date when it is created).xlsx". I tried to do this using code from bellow but I get error - No such file or directory: 'ComparisonReport-13/06/2017.xlsx'... If I put  `writer = pd.ExcelWriter("ComparisonReport.xlsx" )` excel file is created, but I need to have date in the name as well. I also defined variable time1 - `time1 = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`

Code which I tried:

```
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("ComparisonReport-%(s).xlsx" %(time1) )
    myDF.transpose().to_excel(writer, "Results")

    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```

Some ideas why I get error from above?

Comment: did you use window or linux using "/" is bad because it is reserve for directory structure such as Download/report.docx I think it is returning that because it tried to access ComparisonReport-13 Folder, 06 Folder inside and the file call 2017.xlsx therefore it does not exists because you have not create those folder yet try changing the delimiter to "%d-%m-%Y"

Comment: Hi @Hamuel , thanks it worked! :)

Comment: if you use `%Y%m%d`, the reports are sorted by date when sorted by name, and there is no ambiguity between `dayfirst` or `monthfirst`